# Visual C++ 2015, How can I force TlsAlloc to return 0?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am writing a DLL, which is responsible for killing malware (I am reverse engineering malware and writing a mini antivirus specifically for this malware), and it is important that I have access to the thread local storage index #0, because I call a function from the malware to disable it, and it accesses data (encryption keys) from TLS index #0, which I want to copy to my current threads tls index #0.  So I need TlsAlloc to return 0.  However, it is returning 1, which makes me believe that visual studio is generating code which takes this index 0.

How can I disable this so that my program can use the thread local storage index 0?

Comment: I might be getting it wrong, but is the malware running in your app's process? From [TlsAlloc on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801(v=vs.85).aspx): _"TLS indexes are not valid across process boundaries. A DLL cannot assume that an index assigned in one process is valid in another process."_ From the same page: _"The value of the TLS index should be treated as an **opaque value; do not assume that it is an index into a zero-based array**."_ Assuming that what you're asking is possible, did you try it from a simple app (no DLLs)?

Comment: There's no robust way of doing this.  But it is possible to build a program without linking in the C runtime library, e.g., see http://www.drdobbs.com/avoiding-the-visual-c-runtime-library/184416623 (a bit out of date, but it was the first relevant link I could find) which *might* help.

Comment: Why don't you just save the current value stored in index#0, set it to whatever value you want, then restore the old value after the malware code fragment returns?  The fact that the index isn't yours doesn't really matter much in this context, it seems to me.